# Настройка и интеграция Jenkins и Gradle с нуля

Tags: java, git, юнит-тесты, gradle, jenkins

Туториалов много, но каждый охватывает только часть процесса, не могу найти простой и понятный для новичка, охватывающий весь процесс.

Что я хочу:

1. Есть Java приложение (причем, это может быть как web приложение, запускаемое в том же Tomcat, либо обычное консольное приложение или библиотека, собираемая в jar  )
2. Написаны Unit и интеграционные тесты
3. Приложение собирается gradle-ом.
4. Развернут Artifactory с репозиторием, куда я хочу деплоить сборки.

Собственно процесс, который я хочу настроить:

- При каждом пуше на сервере прогоняются unit-тесты, интеграционные тесты, анализируется покрытие кода тестами, codestyle и т.д.
- Если все хорошо, сборка деплоится в Artifactory, а также (если приложение - веб), обновляется и перезапускается на dev сервере.
- Либо иметь некоторую страничку, представляющее собой таблицу: ссылка на скачивание - commit message (для примера: http://abrok.eu/stockfish/)
- Если что-то пошло не так, ответ с описанием приходит на почту (например)

Было бы здорово посмотреть туториал с самого нуля, когда создается helloWorld Java проект, как настраивается Jenkins, что происходит, когда делается commit и т.д. Т.е. туториал, где одновременно с настройкой Jenkins пишется и изменяется java код.

Может быть не обязательно полностью описанный мной процесс, но какой-нибудь туториал, который показывает упрощенно процесс разработки (изменение, написание тестов, коммиты) java приложение при работающем jenkins.

Comment: Я тоже хочу всё это уметь, очень хорошее дело — CDCI. Вот только вопрос не очень понятен в итоге. Вы хотите, чтобы вам дали ссылку на туториал? Наверняка этого не произойдет. Вопрос в целом очень широкий и на него не ответить коротко. Давайте как-нибудь разобьем его на конкретные подзадачи про каждую из которых можно спросить "как правильно сделать А".

Comment: Вообще, туториала на весь процесс почти наверняка нет по этой самой причине — здесь несколько независимых друг от друга процессов.

Comment: Так как я понимаю, что процессы зависимы друг от друга, после пуша - прогон тестов, потом результат.  Если упростить то можно так: git-push - прогон unit тестов - оповещение (в любом виде) о результатах. И вторая подзадача тогда, как интегрировать в процесс дополнительные процессы (например, вставить еще проверку код стайла или деплоймент после код стайла) - это даже важнее, так как подпроцессов может быть различное количество и они могут запускаться в разном порядке.

Comment: Просто прогон Unit-тестов реализуется легко в maven. Наверняка и в Gradle есть средства. Процессы эти зависимы друг от друга, но всё-таки отдельны. Каждый из шагов вашего процесса можно делать разными инструментами, про каждый стоит задавать отдельный вопрос. Если отвечать на ваш вопрос целиком и полностью — целую книгу можно написать )))

Comment: Если вы ещё не знакомы с git-flow, то вам наверняка это будет интересно. Начать можно с описания метки: [tag:git-flow].

Answer (score 6):

Если сфокусироваться на организации процесса сборки средствами Jenkins, получится примерно следующее:

> При каждом пуше на сервере прогоняются unit-тесты, интеграционные тесты, анализируется покрытие кода тестами, codestyle и т.д.

Для проекта (job) задается *триггер сборки* *"Опрашивать SCM об изменениях"* и расписание проверки Git-а на наличие свежих коммитов, например раз в 10 минут. Расписание задается в формате crontab: `H/10 * * * *`.

Другой вариант - выбрать триггер *"Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"* и настроить post-commit hook в репозитории, который будет уведомлять Jenkins о наличии новых коммитов. Для этого достаточно дернуть curl-ом адрес `http://<jenkins_server>/job/<job_name>/build`.

Прогон тестов реализуется вызовом gradle. Установите на билдсервер [Gradle Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) и в качестве основного шага сборки вызывайте gradle, как если бы вы запускали его на локальной машине. Если сборка будет включать в себя прогон тестов, jenkins сохранит информацию о результатах.

> Если все хорошо, сборка деплоится в Artifactory, а также (если приложение - веб), обновляется и перезапускается на dev сервере.

Ставите [Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) и добавляете послесборочный шаг *"Deploy artifacts to Artifactory"*.

Редеплой приложение лучше вынести в отдельный проект, который будет вызываться после основной сборки через *Послесборочную операцию* *"Build other project"*. Чтобы "дотянуться" из проекта деплоя до артефактов основной сборки, установите [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). Вам будет доступен шаг сборки "Copy artifacts from another project", который скопирует нужные файлы из исходной (upstream) сборки.

Саму процедуру деплоя можно реализовать средствами Jenkins (например, [Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin)), средствами gradle (например, [gradle-cargo-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin)) или просто shell-скриптом.

> Если что-то пошло не так, ответ с описанием приходит на почту (например)

Это Jenkins умеет "из коробки", достаточно включить в настройках проекта флажок  *"E-mail Notification"*. Но я рекомендую поставить [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) - он позволяет гибче настраивать события для письма и содержимое.