# Запуск тестов автоматически

Tags: java, gradle, selenium-webdriver

Есть виртуалка для прокрутки тестов.

Тесты написаны на java, selenium WebDriver. Gradle. Теперь задача - нужно настроить так, чтобы тесты постоянно крутились на виртуалке и по прохождении отсылали отчет. С отчетом более менее ясно: Allure, а вот с запуском... как то я потерялся.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, какой в этом смысл? Обычно тесты запускают по какому-то более-менее значимому событию, например, новому коммиту в репозитории

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте [jenkins](https://jenkins.io) и на нем сконфигурируйте запуски тестов по расписанию или по событию. Легко ставится, легко конфигурится, плюс у него удобная web-морда.

Вот здесь обсуждался подобный вопрос: [Настройка и интеграция Jenkins и Gradle с нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446761/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-jenkins-%D0%B8-gradle-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: Да, сейчас его изучаю, но пока непонятно как там и что(

Comment: В вопросе Вы не упомянули репозиторий. Если это git, то jenkins можно настроить на отслеживание каждого push-коммита в git. На каждый push-коммит jenkins может, например, выкачивать проект и запускать maven-сборку с запуском юнит-тестов.

Comment: maven-сборка ... а если на gradle? может вопрос и глупый, но я новичок...

Comment: Я в ответе дал ссылку на подобный вопрос. Посмотрите, плз.